# Помогите с запятой.

Tags: пунктуация

Здравствуйте.

Концовка очень и очень сильная()и тяжёлая.

Ставится ли здесь запятая?

Если да,то почему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Запятая не нужна, так как здесь союзы "и" не являются повторяющимися: первый соединяет два обстоятельства, а второй - два сказуемых.

Answer (score 0):

*И* можно рассматривать как присоединительный союз. Тогда меняется интонация, появляется пауза и ставится запятая. Возможно также тире.

*Концовка очень и очень сильная, и тяжёлая.*

*Концовка очень и очень сильная - и тяжёлая.*

Без паузы:
*Концовка очень и очень сильная и тяжёлая* (в этом случае слегка меняется смысл, можно прочитать: очень и очень тяжелая).

Comment: "Концовка очень и очень сильная, и тяжёлая". Авторский знак: или запятая, или тире, или точка - в зависимости от того эффекта, который хочет вложить в свои слова автор

Answer (score 0):

Экспрессия выражения  хороша только в одном варианте: (1) "Концовка очень и очень (сильная и тяжёлая)". Использование других знаков препинания сделают фразу растянутой и невыразительной.

К сожалению, это оформление может иметь другое смысловое прочтение: (2)"Концовка (очень и очень сильная) и тяжёлая". Этот вариант заметно хуже, но убрать двусмысленность не получается.

Comment: Не вижу экспрессивного преимущества у предложения без запятой. Мне кажется, наоборот, предпочтителен вариант с запятой. Концовка сильная - это хорошо. Концовка тяжелая - это плохо. Эти два утверждения не сочетаются: концовка хорошая и плохая; концовка очень хорошая и плохая; концовка очень хорошая и очень плохая. Скорее так: концовка очень хорошая, но/и при этом кое в чем плохая. Пауза необходима.

Comment: При оценке концовки произведения многое зависит от его жанра : в комедии тяжелый конец неуместен, в трагедии он необходим, а в других случаях это выбор автора, часть его художественного замысла. Так что тяжелый финал нельзя  считать плохим финалом, а вот сильная концовка – это всегда похвала автору. Также можно предположить, что признаки «тяжелый и сильный»  не всегда  противоречат друг другу – более того, мы можем соединить их союзом И, считая, что тяжелое впечатление от такого финала компенсируется чувством удовлетворения художественной силой произведения.

Comment: В этом случае мы используем форму (1): «Концовка очень и очень (тяжелая и сильная)». Вариант (2) «Концовка (очень и очень тяжелая) и сильная» НЕПОНЯТЕН,  так как признаки здесь уже РАЗДЕЛЕНЫ, варианты с запятой (тире) –  то же самое, только РАЗДЕЛЕНИЕ признаков дополнительно ПОДЧЕРКНУТО. Что мы хотим сказать автору: немного поругать и немного похвалить? Но тогда надо изменить форму сообщения, чтобы автор нас понял, например: Концовка очень и очень тяжелая (мрачноватая, пожалуй, здесь ты, брат перестарался), но в то же время сильная (здесь ты молодец).